# How to avoid input string/StringBuilder in an incorrect format error in C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm using a string builder to append text to string.

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(GetStartHTML("installation",string.Empty));
.......
content.AppendFormat("<td>" + idcStepEntity.Comment + "</td>");
```

Unfortunetly i cannot control what comes in from the customer as comment, so i they write something like : *comment { commment] comment* (and they often do) i get string was not in a correct format error.
That mean i should not use a StringBuilder here? Should i use`string += otherstring` or is there any other String class that can bu usefull here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: in what case do you get **input string is not in a correct format** ?

Comment: @SpiderCode, like in the case i wrote, when there is an opening '{' but no ending '}' and some other examples, i dont really understand why this should matter in a string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is possible only with `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` and if your string contains { or }. So the solution is to use `StringBuilder.Append` (as you don`t really use the format part):

```
content.Append("<td>" + idcStepEntity.Comment + "</td>");
```

Comment: This exception is raised when you use `String.Format()` and pass in a string containing "{" as the 1st argument.  The stack trace shows a System.Text.StringBuilder error because String.Format internally uses StringBuilder.  To confirm this: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBox(String.Format("{"))` raises the exception, but `Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBox(String.Format("{0}", "{"))` is fine.

Answer (score 13):

Having an unescaped "{" or "}" in the 1st argument of String.Format() will cause this exception.

**This will cause the exception to be raised:**

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBox(String.Format("{"))
```

**This is OK:**

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBox(String.Format("{0}", "{"))
```

**Solution:**

To escape "{" use "{{" and to escape "}" use "}}.  Depending on your implementation, this could work for you.

```
Dim s As String = "{Hello}"
s = s.Replace("{", "{{")
s = s.Replace("}", "}}")
```

**Stack trace:**

It may appear in the stack trace to be a StringBuilder error because String.Format internally implements System.Text.StringBuilder, but you will get this exception even if you never use a StringBuilder in your project.

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
content.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", idcStepEntity.Comment);
```

Note that, your exception is because your `idcStepEntity.Comment` may contain some block `{}`, then when you pass it into `AppendFormat`, the following overload will be used:

```
AppendFormat(string format, params object[] args);
```

That means it considers your `idcStepEntity.Comment` as the format string and there is not any arguments, that format string contains some invalid block `{}` and hence the exception is thrown.